# Highcharts - How to programmatically toggle legend items and determine which items are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So I have a couple of requests from our designers:

1) Allow users to select/deselect all legend items via clicking a link outside the chart container. This means I need to programmatically toggle all items in the chart on or off, regardless if any are currently selected/deselected.

2) Determine which particular legend items are selected (or enabled) in the chart so that we can generate another chart from the selections.

I don't see a way to do either using the API so I was wondering if anyone has come up with a possible solution for either (or both).

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Highcharts does allow us to toggle the legend states from outside.

`series[0].hide();  series[0].show();`
are provided by highcharts which we can use to implement the functionality you asked for.

here is a fiddle for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/gfNYk/1/

Answer (score 4):

series[i].visible is the property

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of series, **hide()** and **show()** can result in very bad performance. Alternatively you can use **setVisible()** on each series and **redraw()** at the end.

```
    $('#uncheckAll').click(function(){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var series = chart.series;
        for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
            series[i].setVisible(false, false);
        }
        chart.redraw();
    });

    $('#checkAll').click(function(){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var series = chart.series;
        for(i=0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
            series[i].setVisible(true, true);
        }
        chart.redraw();
    });
```

to determine if a series is selected you can use the **series.visible** property